# Как на python telebot отправить вступительное сообщение для пользователя?

Tags: python, telebot

Необходимо отправить сообщение для пользователя, перешедшему к диалогу с ботом, если это возможно. Например, при переходе к диалогу пользователю должно прийти сообщение: "Привет!".

Замечание: бот должен первым написать сообщение*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое **невозможно**, бот  должен получить от тебя первое сообщение. Можно только так...

```css
import telebot 

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start(message):
    if  message.text.lower() == "/start":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")  
        

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```